# Mlab Uri not woking

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab

I have tried a lot to search but didn't get solution so I am asking.

Through Mongo shell I am able to access data from **mlab** database but accessing it through URI i'm getting this error :

> MongoError: not authorized on try to execute command { find:
>   "result1", filter: { info: { $regex: "02420703114.*" } } }

User have roles :

```
"roles": [
    {
        "role": "dbOwner",
        "db": "cbpgec-result"
    }
]
```

help please!!
thanks in advance

Comment: The error says you are attempting to run that command on a database named “try”. Are you sure you’re connecting to the correct database name? If you add your code to the question we can probably see where the error might be. (Just make sure to remove the username and password from your connection string if you add it to the question)

Comment: actually i'm using database "try" locally for testing my app but at the time of deployment i have changed it to : "mongodb://<dbusername>:<dbpassword>@ds133657.mlab.com:33657/cbpgec-result"  i think mongodb package saved database name in its cache and trying to access that? correct me if i'm wrong  and please tell how to resolve it

Comment: thanks for help..it worked after reinstalling the mongodb package

Comment: There are a couple of reasons this might be happening. Can you add your code to the question? Should be able to spot the problem in the code.

Comment: Oh okay! Glad to hear it’s working. FYI you can always reach out to support@mlab.com too if you need any help.